# Only perform sed operations on lines starting with a particular string

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, files, scripting

I have the following file format

```
Received from +11231231234 at 2021-10-10T19:56:50-07:00:
This is a message that contains words like from, at, etc.

Sent to +11231231234 at 2021-10-11T06:50:57+00:00:
This is another message that contains words like to, at, etc.
```

I want to clean up the "Received" and "Sent" lines, the following sed commands achieves this

```
cat file |  sed 's/from//g' | sed 's/to/    /g' | sed 's/+\w\+//' | sed 's/at//g' | \
sed 's/T/ /g' | sed 's/[[:digit:].]*\:$//' | sed 's/[[:digit:].]*\:$//' | sed 's/-$//' |  \
sed 's/-$//' | sed 's/+$//'
```

and results in the following

```
Received    2021-10-10 19:56:50
This is a message that contains words like  ,  , etc.

Sent        2021-10-11 06:50:57
This is another message that contains words like  ,  , etc.
```

As you can see it does clean up the "Received" and "Sent" lines nicely. But it also cleans up the message lines! How can I apply these operations only on lines starting with "Received" and "Sent" ?

Comment: [Crosspost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378870/apply-sed-operations-only-to-lines-beginning-with-a-particular-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what addresses in sed are for:

```
sed -E '/^(Received|Sent) (from|to) \+[0-9]+ at/ s/ .*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T([0-9:]{8}).*/        \1 \2/'
```

- The address means the substitution is only applied on lines that start with `Received` or `Sent` followed by `from` or `to`, `+` followed by a number and `at`.
- The substitution starts matching at a space, it captures the date (`[0-9]{4}` is *a digit repeated four times* etc.); it matches the `T` and again captures the time. What comes after the time is matched, but not captured. Then, the whole matched part is replaced with several spaces and the captured date and time.

Comment: is it all possible to explain the syntax of this?

Comment: @jf4i2d: Updated.